# C# app.UseRequestLocalization - how to map zh-CN to zh-Hans-CN

Tags: c#

I have a C# API that returns localized content.

The localization is configured in Startup.cs as follows:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
    .SetDefaultCulture("en-US")
);
```

Most of our clients pass in zh-Hans-CN or  zh-Hant-TW in the `Accept-Language` for Chinese.

However, some Android clients are passing in zh-CN or zh-TW.  I would like to be able to support both.

The obvious solution is to duplicate all the `*.zh-Hans.resx` files and rename them `*.zh-CN.resx` and then add zh-CN to the supportedCultures array.  However, I hate duplicated code/files.

I could also use `.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(...)` and basically re-write the query string / cookie / header parsing, but I don't want to duplicate the logic.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()

    // Does a method like this exist, that is executed for each of the built in
    // query string / cookie / header culture code look ups before comparing it 
    // to the supported cultures array?
    .MapCultureCode((string cultureCode) =>
        string.Equals(cultureCode, "zh-CN", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "zh-Hans-CN" :
        string.Equals(cultureCode, "zh-TW", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "zh-Hant-TW" :
        cultureCode)

    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
    .SetDefaultCulture("en-US")
);
```

Does anyone know if this can be accomplished?

Comment: Perhaps a custom culture provider that does the mapping to a culture you have resources for: [Use a custom provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-a-custom-provider)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12263

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing:

1. Include "zh-CN" etc. in the supported cultures array.  "zh-CN" is supported, so I'm happy with it in the supportedCultures array.
2. Add this code snippet AFTER the `app.UseRequestLocalization(...)`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var cultureMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "zh-CN", "zh-Hans-CN" },
        { "zh-TW", "zh-Hant-TW" }
    };

    if (cultureMap.TryGetValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, out string mappedCultureName))
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(mappedCultureName);
    }

    await next(context);
});
```

Now I don't have to duplicate resx files or any logic that checks CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.

Updated:

Alternative:

```
public class CultureMapMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _cultureMap = new(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        { "zh-CN", "zh-Hans-CN" },
        { "zh-TW", "zh-Hant-TW" }
    };

    public CultureMapMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (_cultureMap.TryGetValue(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, out string mappedCultureName))
        {
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(mappedCultureName);
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline.
        await _next(context);
    }
}

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
    .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
    .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
    .SetDefaultCulture("en-US")
);

app.UseMiddleware<CultureMapMiddleware>();
```